# В чем выполняются корутины?

Tags: python, asyncio

Пусть есть код:

```
import asyncio


async def fetch():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*[fetch() for _ in range(5)])


asyncio.run(main())
```

Он выполнится за ~1 секунду.

С одной стороны код запускается в одном процессе и одном потоке. С другой стороны функции `fetch` "спят" параллельно. Здесь у меня возникает непонимание. Знаю, что `asyncio.sleep` неблокирующая функция. Но как реализуется способность не блокировать поток? В чем "спит" функция `asyncio.sleep`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В 2х словах слово await выполняет 2 действия: входит в цикл ( который выполняет другие асинхронные функции) и возвращается в функцию которая его вызвала.

Если говорить упрощенно, то выполняет всё loop, который является списком задач.

При каждом слове await программа проваливается к этому циклу.

В цикле проверяется готовность других корутин и проваливается к строчке после первой готовой. Там выполняется обычный код до следующего await или до выхода из функции.

Если готовых нет, то исполняется вход в асинхронные функции и выполнение в них обычного кода до слова await.

В случае создания тасков корутины добавляются в список на выполнение, но без прерывания текущей функции.

### Почему asyncio.sleep не блокирует?

На каждом входе в loop исполняется встроенный таймер и проверка дескрипторов на готовность к чтению или записи (select и тп).

Таймер проверяет когда должен закончится ближайший sleep и если время пришло, то возвращается в функцию где ждут его await-ом.

### Уточнения

дескрипторы - это файлы, сокеты, пайпы, ком порты и вроде именованные каналы.

await - крутит луп пока не исполнится таск, а потом возвращает результат.

Каждая асинхронная функция где-то в глубине упирается в неблокирующий сокет,  другой дескриптор или в таймер. На этом месте она прерывается и не выполняется далее.

Луп с помощью select (poll или подобного, зависит от ОС) проверяет записала ли ОС что-то в сокеты, если что-то есть - то уже читает его. `select` - функция которая выбирает готовый

Питон возвращает на await в функцию где-то в глубине, которая возвращает на другой await и так далее до вашего кода.

Ваш код исполняется до конца функции или до следующего await.

В этом месте если вызвать что-то блокирующее (time.sleep(10)), то loop не провернется. Также если будете выполнять тяжелую математику другие прерванные таски не очнутся. Для циклов с математикой кстати делай `await asyncio.sleep(0)` для "паралельной" (именно в кавычках) работы

Comment: select, дескрипторы - это все механизмы ОС, которые позволяют в пределах одного потока выполнять более одной задачи?

Comment: Нет, задача выполняется всегда одна в одном потоке. Другие задачи просто прерываются на время. `select` это механизм который помогает определить какая именно должна выполнится. дескриптор это указатель на файл или сокет, который проверяется

Comment: "Другие задачи просто прерываются на время" - вот здесь у меня и возникает непонимание. С await-ами как таковыми понятно, и циклом событий. Но что под капотом? То есть ожидание то происходит, но не в потоке, раз оно не блокирует его. Но где тогда, если поток всегда один? Это как-то связано с неблокирующими сокетами ОС?

Comment: Это как-то связано с неблокирующими сокетами ОС? - это если говорить про сетевое взаимодействие, а не asyncio.sleep

Comment: @АльбертАлександров добавил в ответ.